# significance test of a coefficient of a log-log regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, t-test, regression-coefficients

let's say I have the following model `log(y) ~ log(x1) + log(x2)` and I want to test the if an increase of `1% in x1` will will result in an increase of more than `0.2% in y`.

Due to the fact that we have a `log-log` regression, `t` should be calculated as follows: `t = (b1 - 0.2)/Std. Error`

I base my assumption on the fact that in a `log - log regression` an increase of `1% in X` yields a change of `b% in y`

am I interpreting right or is there an error?

Comment: It depends on what you might mean by "increase of."  Regressions like this tell you nothing about what will happen when you alter the characteristics of any given subject so as to increase their value of $x_1$ by $1\%$.  You are testing whether the (population) coefficient of $\log(x_1)$ exceeds $0.2$, nothing more than that.

Comment: @whuber I understand, but is my formula for `t` correct?